# cv2.setMouseCallback() is not working in Colab

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
prevX,prevY=-1,-1
def printCoordinate(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global prevX,prevY
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,(255,255,255),-1)
        strXY='('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')'
        font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
        cv2.putText(img,strXY,(x+10,y-10),font,1,(255,255,255))
        if prevX==-1 and prevY==-1:
            prevX,prevY=x,y
        else:
            cv2.line(img,(prevX,prevY),(x,y),(0,0,255),5)
            prevX,prevY=-1,-1
        cv2_imshow(img)
img = np.zeros((800,800,3),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2_imshow(img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',printCoordinate)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to draw line or polygon with mouse clicks on an image and need to coordinates of the points of line and polygon.
But the code crashes when it reaches line "cv2.setMouseCallback('image',printCoordinate)". Can anyone please guide me how can I fix it on colab?
PS: On my local PC the code works fine but it does not work on Colab.

I have replaced the cv2.imshow to cv2_imshow as .imshow is not supported by colab.

Comment: This function will never work in colab because its a remote server, you need to use a completely different approach.